# CSS: Centering elements in a div while keeping the text left-align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to have all the elements in my div (which is a bootstrap column actually) while keeping the text in there left-align.
So my code looks like this :
I want the p, span and a to be horizontally centered, while their content (the texts) should be left-align.

```
<div class='col-sm-4 col-md-4'>
  <p>...</p>
  <span>...</span>
  <a>...</a>
</div>
```

(the number of columns varies, I have 3 here, but that could be more really).

What I tried to do in my css was to add some left-padding in percentages according to the number of columns. It does work quite well, but I am sure there is an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Where is your CSS that you have tried?

Comment: ^ Answer above and have you tried using css `text-align:` ?

Comment: Do you want to left align the children on the bounds containing all children or on the respective child's bounds?

Comment: What's wrong with add left/right padding? Sounds like a better solution to me

Answer (score 0):

by the way, dont forget to add "class=" ;).

If i understood you right, there are two possibilities.

first:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4">
   <p>...</p>
   <span>...</span>
   <a>...</a>
</div>
</div>
```

This would create an offset of "col-md-4". Thus, 4 - 4 - 4, it would be centered.

Another, neater solution would be:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="wrapper" style="width:300px;position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
   <p>...</p>
   <span>...</span>
   <a>...</a>
</div>
</div>
```

That way you create a wrapper that is centered through setting the margins left and right automatically. 
For that solution you need to provide the position(relative etc, but not static) and the width!

hope it helps.

Comment: I think your second solution is more inline with what the OP is looking for. You don't need to provide `position: relative;` on the element though. A specified width and right/left margin set to auto is all that is needed to center the element if it is block level;